# How to make a .py script readable by another python script?

Tags: python, analysis, converters

I want to build a program (in Python) which is analysing other Python scripts. Therefor I need a way to make .py-files readable for a Python program.

I thought about simply converting .py to .txt and then using .startswith and .find methods. Is there a way to convert .py to .txt?

Also feel free to tell other ways for analysing. Important is that structures like if-statements or loops and indentation-levels get figured out.

Comment: If you just want to read the "text" from a file, it needn't have an extension ".txt" per se. A file extension doesn't play a role in this. You can read text from any file. Just do `open("file.py","r")` and read from the file handler.

Comment: .py files / Python scripts are text files, no conversion needed.

Comment: The [ast](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) module can be used for this kind of task, but it's quite low-level.

Answer (score 3):

> Also feel free to tell other ways for analysing. Important is that structures like if-statements or loops and indentation-levels get figured out.

If you want to preserve this kind of structure in exactly the same way that Python would itself parse the file, you should use the standard library `ast` module (https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html). AST means "abstract syntax tree": the representation of the code as Python understands it.

The basic usage pattern is to call `ast.parse(file)` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.parse) on the file you want to parse. You'll get back an object (https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.AST) which is the top of a tree of AST nodes.

You may be interested in picking through the source code for `black` (https://github.com/psf/black), which is a Python code formatter that uses `ast` to validate that the formatted code has the exact same behavior as the code it was originally run on.